# Mocking service in AngularJS HTTP

Tags: angularjs, http, mocking, jasmine

I'm trying to test a controller that does an http request through a service.

Should I just mock the service and return a default value, rather than doing an actual http request, or using `$httpBackend`.

I'm testing in Jasmine by the way.

Thanks.

Comment: mockService = {
                getApi: function(url: string) {
                    return "hello world";
                }
            }
            createCtrl = function() {
                return $controller('homeCtrl', {$scope: scope, 'dataService': mockService})
            };

Comment: Here you can see that I'm trying to add a mockservice to my controller, however, when I call the getMessage() method in my controller in the test, which in turn would call the getApi("afdlasf") method in my service, it seems to still be using the real service and not the mocked one. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use `$httpBackend`

Since you need to mock the response also

```
$httpBackend.when("GET",'URL').respond(respnonse);
```

response contains the value that you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** Don't do an actual http-request.

- **UNIT-TESTS**
  When doing proper unit-tests, you only test a single unit. This can be a class or only a part of a class. This means that you have to mock the dependencies. In your case it would mean that you'd mock the service to simply act as the class would. So returning a promise containing a data-model.
  **pro**: The biggest advantage of true unit-tests is speed. You can perform a huge amount of unit tests instead of a single end-to-end test.
  **con**: The biggest disadvantage of unit-tests is that when you change a dependency to work in a different way, your tests will still succeed because the service has been mocked.
- **INTEGRATION-TESTS**
  An integration test works almost a a unit-test, but here you don't mock direct dependencies. In your case, when doing an integration-test, you would not mock the service, rather it's dependencies (with $httpBackend).
  **pro**: Still quite fast, and offers even more robust tests. Because when you update the direct dependencies, the classes you test can fail because they are not mocked.
  **con**: Not quite as fast as an unit-test, but still very fast.
- **END-TO-END**
  E2E tests test the entire application, not mocking anything. This includes all XHR-calls to an api.
  **pro**: Since nothing is mocked, it always covers the entire application. And it is very useful to track DOM-changes and browser-compability. It can even automatically take screenshots to give a real view of the rendered data.
  **con**: it's slow. Because it performs actual API-calls these tests can take a while to perform.

So to answer your question, it depends what you're writing. When you write proper unit-tests you should mock the service:

```
$provide.service('DataService', ['$q', function($q) { 
  this.get = function() {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
      if (requestFailed) {
        reject('The request failed');
      }

      resolve(APIData);
    });
  };
}]);
```

If you're doing integartion-tests, you should mock the actual $http-request using `$httpBackend`.

```
it('should request data', function() {
  $httpBackend
    .expect('GET', url)
    .respond(APIData);

  expect($scope.list.count).toEqual(0);

  $scope.clickRetrieve();
  $httpBackend.flush();

  expect($scope.list.count).toBeGreaterThan(0);
});
```

I'm working on quite a big application an have not to much experience in testing. But my favorite testing-type is by far integration-testing. I've had some issues with unit-tests that didn't reveal breaking changes due to the mocked services. Since I've all but switched to integrated tests, where I mock almost exclusively my data-services.

*side-note*: I work using data-services which act as a layer between my application and the API, if the API is updated, in theory I should only update the data-service as no class except the repository accesses these. 
This way I can ensure that in my application I only work with DataModels instead of simple Objects, and that I use `undefined`, not `null`.